# How to add multiple style sheets using chrome.tabs.insertCSS?

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have a bit of code in my chrome extension that calls `chrome.tabs.insertCSS()` multiple times in succession (needed because of optional styling selected by user).  The problem is not that the code doesn't work, but that it *does* work, and yet I'm still getting an error in the console: `Attempting to use a disconnected port object`.  In related code I'm using `chrome.tabs.connect()`, so part of me thinks that this could be solved by sending that message through that already connected port, but I can't find a way to do that.

I assume that `chrome.tabs.insertCSS()` using messaging underneath, so it stands to reason that there should be a way to have it use a port that is already in use.

**My question is this:  Is it possible to tell the `chrome.tabs.insertCSS` method to use an already existing and open port as opposed to opening another?  If not, what is the most efficient/common way to load multiple css/script files dynamically into a tab from my background page?**

My background page:

```
function setUpListener() {
    chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (msg, sender, respond) {
        if (msg["injectCss"]) { 
            var port = chrome.tabs.connect(sender.tab.id, { name: "injection" });
            port.postMessage({ beginInject: msg.injectCss.files.length });
            injectCss(port, sender.tab.id, msg.injectCss.files, 0, function (port) {
                port.postMessage({ endInject: true });
                port.disconnect();
                respond();
            });
        }
        return true;
    });
}

function injectCss(port, tab, files, index, callback) {
    // TODO: try getting/compiling all .css files instead
    chrome.tabs.insertCSS(tab, { file: files[index++], runAt: "document_start" }, function () {
        if (index > files.length)
            return callback(port);
        return injectCss(port, tab, files, index, callback);
    });
}
```

**EDIT:** I've also considered compiling all the necessary CSS into one file as opposed to calling `insertCSS` multiple times, but I can't seem to find out how to get the contents of those files from my background script.

Comment: Could you show your current code to make it easier to reproduce your problem?

Comment: Added the relavent code to the post.

Comment: I guess that you're calling `chrome.runtime.sendMessage({injectCss:[]})` from the content script? You're right in your "TODO" remark, the current code looks very messy and can be improved using XHR. However, the title of your question does not really allow for such an answer, so I refrain from posting it. Please edit your question to make it more complete (so I don't need to guess for details or intended meaning) (don't forget about a meaningful title - what would you type in Google if you were looking for an answer to your question?).

Comment: Updated question.  Again.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing all of the code related to your use of the messaging API, I cannot be specific about the "disconnected port" error you're observing. You're probably shutting down the port before your asynchronous `injectCss` method is called (either by calling `.disconnect()` or by unloading the page).

Your current way of inserting multiple CSS files is okay, but I would put the `index > files.length` check at the top of the `insertCss` function to make sure that the callback is called when no style sheets are defined:

```
function injectCss(port, tab, files, index, callback) {
    if (index > files.length) {
        callback(port);
    } else {
        chrome.tabs.insertCSS(tab, { file: files[index] }, function () {
            injectCss(port, tab, files, index + 1, callback);
        });
    }
}
```

---

Regarding your second question (how to concatenate all CSS files) before inserting it: This can easily be achieved using multiple `XMLHttpRequest` calls (see below). I don't see why you want to use this method though, calling `insertCSS` multiple times is just as effective, and has an advantage over the next method: If one file is invalid CSS (e.g. because a curly brace is missing), the other files won't be affected when you use multiple `chrome.tabs.insertCSS` calls.

```
function injectCss(port, tab, files, callback) {
    var allCss = new Array(files.length);
    var tasksToGo = files.length;
    if (tasksToGo === 0) {
        callback();
        return;
    }
    files.forEach(function(file, index) {
        var x = new XMLHttpRequest();
        x.open('GET', chrome.runtime.getURL(file));
        x.onload = function() {
            allCss[index] = x.responseText;
            if (--tasksToGo === 0) {
                chrome.tabs.insertCSS(tab.id, {
                    code: allCss.join('\n')
                }, callback);
            };
        };
        x.onerror = function() {
            // TODO: What if a file is missing?
        };
        x.send();
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  The approach I finally took is similar to this; I'm recursively calling `jQuery.ajax()` and concatenating the files as the come in, which increased overall performance.  I'm still getting the port error, though, which as you say can't be debugged without seeing my code.  I'll have to figure that one out on my own.